# 'Git' Not Authenticating due to Password Authentication Being Removed

Tags: git, github, push

I need to push a cloned repo back to Github, but when I run `git push -u -f origin main` in the folder that I've initialized and added a remote origin to, it returns this error:

```bash
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.
remote: Please see https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls for information on currently recommended modes of authentication.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/BusyBird15/WeatherOne.git/'
```

How do I authenticate myself when the main authentication method has been removed?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+remote%3A+Support+for+password+authentication+was+removed+on+August+13%2C+2021

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main authentication method for GitHub is SSH, which you can read about in their documentation: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh

As a summary, partially taken from GitHub own documentation, you should:

1. Generate a SSH key, using for it a command like:  `ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "your_email@example.com"`
2. If using linux, modify the permissions of the key files with `chmod 600 keyFile`
3. Add the key to your GitHub profile, under Settings -> SSH keys
4. Add the key to your git installation, with `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519`

You'll have to then adjust your origins to point to the ssh endpoints of your repository. The one you linked would be: `git@github.com:BusyBird15/WeatherOne.git`

Comment: Actually I needed to change the remote origin to contain a PAT I got from Github, and with this and the SSH key I was able to successfully push it.